# Query to extract a row containig particular string from a particular column in sql?

Tags: mysql

**Table Name** : products **Column 1**: id  **Column 2**:product_category

```
       id  product_category
       1   ["14","20"]
       2   ["14","20","15"]
       3   ["214","26"]
```

How to get the ids which have only the category id 14.

Comment: Try to use `FIND_IN_SET` of mysql.

Comment: database design is broken. product_category needs to be another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like:
SELECT id FROM table WHERE category_id like '%"14"%';